# Question about Analogy to Statistics

Tags: bias, sample, population

If anyone could help me verify if my analogy is correct, thanks so much!

Here is an analogy:

A population is like a pot of soup.

We stir the pot of soup with the ladle because naturally the contents of the soup can sink down or separate. This act of stirring is called Randomization.

If we don't stir the soup, then when we scoop it with the ladle, you may get too much of contents at the bottom, and that would not be a good representation of how a typical bowl of that soup tastes like. So stirring the soup helps make the overall pot representative for sampling, just like how Randomization helps gives us a more representative sample and guard us against Bias.

Bias is the tendency of a statistic to overestimate or underestimate the population parameter you’re trying to measure. In this case, if we do not stir the pot of soup, we may have too much salt or fat scooped at once, which gives us a bowl of soup that is too salty or not too salty. This is an overestimate or underestimate of the salt level of the soup.

A scoop from the ladle is a single sample, and the sample size is the size of ladle itself.

However, typically a bowl of soup is filled through multiple scoops of the ladle. So, a bowl of soup is like a large sample with N number of scoops.

Just like how in real life, we work with one large sample with N number of smaller samples combined.

Let me know what you think!

Comment: I think the classic 'coloured marbles' stories are easier to follow because the samples (marbles) are discrete entities there. Think of two or more colours put in a bag one after another, mixed vs. unmixed.

Comment: @mkt That's a great one too! Do you see any errors in my current analogy?

Comment: I would say that sample size is the *number of 'scoops'* and not the size of the ladle. And this is I think where the continuous nature of 'soup volume' complicates things and introduces confusion. In the marble analogy, there is no variation in marble size (=variation in ladle size), only variation in the number of marbles you collect (=number of ladle scoops). I'm not totally sure about the rest of the analogy but I don't find it especially enlightening.

Answer (score 10):

I think this isn't bad, but I agree with @mkt 's comments. You want something discrete.

I think an even better analogy is one that I saw Andrew Gelman use in a class.

Get a bunch of individually wrapped candies of different sizes. Put them in a bag (population). Now, take out a handful (sample). Get the average weight of the candies in your hand (statistic, or parameter estimate). That's a sample for estimating the average weight of the candies in the whole bag.

But, be careful! When he did this in class, everyone got a biased estimate because, when you mix candies, the bigger ones go to the bottom (bias).

IIRC, this was a class on 'teaching statistics'.  Gelman also has a book *Teaching Statistics: A Bag of Tricks* and I'm pretty sure this one is in there.

I think this has a couple advantages over your method. First, the candies are discrete, like observations are. Second, the weight of the candies is measurable and precise, whereas the taste of the soup is vague. Third, it also teaches that you have to be careful with your sampling and randomizing! Sometimes, mixing isn't what it seems to be.

Comment: RE: the bigger ones go to the bottom (bias) -- unless the candies are grossly different in densities or shaped in a very peculiar way, in general larger things will actually tend to 'float' on the top when mixed up. Smaller things have more ability to fall through the interstitial gaps created by the larger things. Probably a good extension on understanding what you think is biased in one way may indeed be biased in a completely different way and the importance of thoroughly researching the phenomena trying to be described statistically.

Comment: Well, in Gelman's demo, the big candies went to the bottom. That makes some intuitive sense to me, but I can't explain the physics or mechanics of it.